# javascript regex to validate decimal datatype

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate the decimal datatype in the incoming feed. Integer part and the fraction value combined together can have up to 7 chars. Fraction value is optional. Leading + or - is also optional.

For example DECIMAL(7, 2) defines numbers of the form 12345.67

[test case](https://regex101.com/r/OGmKWA/1)

```
Valid
-1
+1
1
+.1
-.1
.1
+11111.11
-11111.11
11.11
11111

Invalid
1111111
11.11111
0.111111
.1111111
+111111.11
-111111.11
+11111.111
-11111.111
11111.111
111111.11
+1.
-1.
1.
```

This is what I currently use

```
[+-]?\d\.?\d?
```

How should I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CVFhSy/6)

Comment: I've added explanation of lookahead used in answer.

Comment: Sorry @anubhava I made a blunder. I have edited the test cases.

Comment: DECIMAL(7, 2) defines numbers of the form 12345.67, so the fraction part is given 2 chars and the rest 5 chars go to integer.

Comment: Cool, so `(?=(?:\D*\d){1,7}$)` has any relevance in the new snippet, I feel it is redundant.